# JQuery filter using :contains

Tags: jquery, filter, contains

I am new to all this and struggling with identifying a parent element when using :contains to filter a bunch of divs? 
My end result is to have 3 buttons that when clicked check if a div contains a specific word and if so apply a class to the containing div, and another class to all other divs.. essentially hiding and showing them.

I have a fiddle which doesn't work but show the idea I am trying to create.

The code that I know doesn't work but gives the process is;

```
$(".manchester").click(function (e) {
    if ($('.address:contains("Manchester")').length) {
        $('holder').addClass('visible');
    }
    if ($('.address:contains("London")').length) {
        $('.holder').addClass('invisible');
    }
    if ($('.address:contains("Paris")').length) {
        $('.holder').addClass('invisible');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and the fiddle lives at http://jsfiddle.net/2fEzS/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic is wrong, you don't actually filter the elements, instead of defining several handlers, you can minify the code by using textContent of the clicked element. I'd suggest:

```
$(".filter div").click(function(e) {
    $('.holder').hide() // hide all the selected elements
                .filter(':contains(' + $(this).text()  + ')')
                .show(); // show the filtered elements
});
```

Or:

```
$(".filter div").click(function (e) {
    $('.holder').addClass('invisible')
                .removeClass('visible')
                .filter(':contains(' + $(this).text()  + ')')
                .removeClass('invisible')
                .addClass('visible');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kdRzQ/

Note that `div` element shouldn't be used as a button and it doesn't have a default action to be prevented, so `preventDefault` doesn't do anything in your code. Also if there are many elements in the document, it would be better to cache the elements outside the context of the click handler:

```
var $holders = $('.holder');   
$(".filter div").click(function (e) {
    $holders.addClass('invisible') // ...
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to add "Show All" button that resets the filter?

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding all the `div`s with the class `.holder` instead of just the one that affect the `contains` bit.

Change your code to:

```
$(".manchester").click(function (e) {
    $('.address:contains("Manchester")').closest('.holder').addClass('visible');
    $('.address:contains("London")').closest('.holder').addClass('invisible');
    $('.address:contains("Paris")').closest('.holder').addClass('invisible');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It is case sensitive though so if a `div` contains 'paris' instead of 'Paris' that won't get hidden.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2fEzS/19/